# How to keep duplicate key-values in AngularJS $http.get response?

Tags: angularjs, json

When I get a JSON file with duplicate keys using $http.get, the response only has the last key-value pair for duplicate keys.

JSON - data.json:

```
{
    "hello": [{"cell" : "1"}],
    "hello": [{"cell" : "2"}]
}
```

call to $http.get:

```
$http.get("data.json").success(
         function(response) {
             console.log(response);
         }
);
```

But the response only contains

```
{"hello": [{"cell" : "2"}]}
```

Is it possible to get the json object with multiple key-value pairs with the same key? Thanks.

Comment: The question is why? If these items have the same key, why not group them? Also, to answer your question take a look on this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234214/multiple-objects-with-the-same-key).

Comment: You can pass it as array `[{"hello": [{"cell": "1"}]},{"hello": [{"cell": "2"}]}]`